# Template not being loaded with Kmodule.xml config in Drools

Tags: jboss, drools, rule-engine

I am trying to load my drools template file(drt) with kmodule.xml as below.

```
 <kbase packages="KieRule">
        <ruleTemplate
                dtable="kiedrl/template-data.xls"
                template="kiedrl/validate-schedule-minor.drt"
                row="3" col="2" />
        <ksession name="templateRule" />
  </kbase>
```

and my template and data table are present in resouces folder as shown in below image.

[image]

and I am creating a session as follows

```
 KieSession ksession = KieServices.Factory.get().getKieClasspathContainer().newKieSession("templateRule");
```

But my template is not able to load into session. Any other configuration that I need to add in pom.xml or at any other?

Comment: where is your kmodule.xml ? it's not in your screenshot of the directory structure.

Comment: I edited for ur reference.

Comment: what version are you using?

Comment: 7.54.0.Final version

Comment: Are you getting an error? How do you know that your template isn't loading?